# How to center elements in navbar

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have an issue centering the elements of my navbar in my page. I think that is something related to the CSS file, but I can't find the error, please help me out.

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}

p,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div,
li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header_nav {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #fff 20%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .6) 60%);
  display: flex;
  height: 60px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.global_nav_item {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.global_nav_item:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #42210b;
}

.global_nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.logo {
  width: 120px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo img {
  width: 100%;
}

.section_inner {
  padding: 50px 10% 30px;
}

.key {
  height: 500px;
  background: center / cover no-repeat url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mathi4k2/hello-world/main/dic_cafe/images/sample_key.jpg");
  font-family: 'Noto Serif JP', serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.key h1 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.visual-key h1,
.visual-key p {
  margin-top: 80px;
  text-align: left;
}

#menu {
  background: center / cover no-repeat url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mathi4k2/hello-world/main/dic_cafe/images/sample_menu_bg.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center bottom;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="header_nav">
    <a href="index.html" class="logo"><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mathi4k2/hello-world/main/dic_cafe/images/sample_logo_k.png"></a>
    <ul class="global_nav">
      <a href="index.html" class="global_nav_item">
        <li>Home</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#menu" class="global_nav_item">
        <li>Menu</li>
      </a>
      <a href="contact.html" class="global_nav_item">
        <li>Contact</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="key section_inner visual-key">
    <h1>DIC Coffee</h1>
    <p>natural organic cafe</p>
  </div>
</header>
```

I've tried to center the elements with different combinations of commands, and checked the CSS file if there's some other part of the code that changes the properties of my HTML element but didn't find anything.

Comment: Please keep your example [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Only share the code related to your problem. You'll most likely get useful helps that way. Welcome to SO, by the way.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

the .header-nav class has justify-content:space-between; set on it. Remove it, then add justify-content:center; and width:100%; to .global_nav

The justify-content:space-between; was forcing the .global-nav to be right justified.